# Bind a shortcut to a command

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a way of binding a shortcut to a command under Windows 7? My problem is that to type: È I have to press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>2</kbd>" that is stupid and counterintuitive.

I'd like to bind it to something more meaningful like <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>2</kbd> with the accented è (Italian keyboard).

Is there a way of getting this? Maybe modifying the right registers...

Thanks for your help

Comment: Having an Italian keyboard doesn't help us to know what the layout is; a quick Google of Italian keyboard shows countless different layouts. What is the model of your keyboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows, the alt key *is* the shortcut.

You could use a program like [AutoHotKeys](http://www.autohotkey.com/) which will do it for you.

Some people have success whilst holding down <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> key (to right of <kbd>space bar</kbd>).

You could also choose the appropriate 'unicode' for the regional language you want to use (Control Panel then Language Settings).

However, you're only going to save stroke or 2 at best. Even your question about pressing something like <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> + "Key" is actually the same amount of keystrokes as <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>2</kbd>

Comment: First thanks for the powerful instrument you have showed me. As for the "saved strokes" I'm aware of it but I really cannot tolerate Alt+212 to type something that should be typed with an appropriate key combination like the one I said :-)

Comment: Yes, I appreciate it does make sense although what you're really after is a 'function' key (hence my question in your OP about knowing the model)

Comment: Excuse my terrible ignorance but under Control Panel --> keyboard --> properties --> details I was looking for the model of it but I found only voices like: Bus Legacy, Class Name, ID hardware, GUID bus type... The only "meaningful" for my purpose entry seems to be Productor: standard keyboard. And this doesn't help at all... Where is the model? Thanks

Comment: Try device manager, or see if there is a sticker under your keyboard (pick up your keyboard and look underneath).

Comment: Snap... Model No: SK-8825 (L) lenovo standard keyboard :-)

Comment: I created an autohotkey program, put its link into the startup folder and now I have automatically Shift+è = È!! Thank you very much, you gave me a very powerful thing to play with!!

Comment: Excuse me @Dave, do you have an idea why using hotkey if I choose the combination +è::È I'm no more able to type this { which has an hotkey Shift-Alt-è??? It's like the Alt is not considered, do you know why??